# How to set a controller file from a subfolder within a route file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, ionic-framework, vmc

I'm working on a ionic project. I have the following app structure...

`app
  |__dashboard
     |__dashboard.html
     |__dashboard.module.js
     |__controller.js
  |__app.js
  |__config.js
index.html`

I have a controller defined inside the **controller.js**. That is:

```
angular.module('dashboard').controller('Ctrl', function(){
   console.log('hello');
});
```

And I have a route in my **app.js**. That is:

```
.
.
.
$stateProvider
.state('app', {
  url: 'app/',
  abstract: true
  })

.state('app.home', {
  url: '/home',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.html',
      controller: 'Ctrl'
    }
  }
});
```

In my index.html I call all the files:

However, when I run the app, I get the following error: 
`Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'Ctrl' is not a function, got undefined`

Someone can help me please? Thanks!!!

Comment: Is that script file loading in browser dev tools network or sources?

Comment: Please show us your index page.

Comment: My app is loading from Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include **controller.js** script file in your **index.html** so that you can make use of that controller in **routing**. Include your controller as:

```
<script src="/app/dashboard/controller.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've included the file. It also shows a console.log but it seems that my route does not recognize my controller.